# SVG тэг начинает работать только после изменения innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, svg

Что имею:

- сервер на локалхосте, написан полностью вручную на нативном NodeJS
- `content-type` заголовок страницы отдаётся как `text/html; charset=utf-8`
- тэг `<!DOCTYPE html>` присутствует

История такова, что я захотел добавить рисованный прямоугольник на свой сайт, в codepen он работает хорошо и сама отдача страницы у них настроена также: https://codepen.io/Diskyp/pen/rNapGzM

Я добавил получившийся код на мой локальный сайт и схематично получилось что-то вроде такого:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="block1">
      <div class="block2">
        <svg>
          <polygon points="10 20, 300 10, 300 120, 10 80"/>
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="side-block">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Однако `svg` элемент и полигон ничего не отрисовывали, имели 0х0 размер и не поддавались никаким изменениям.

После многих часов разбирательств с попытками писать самые различные `xmlns` атрибуты, я невообразимым образом установил, что после того как я юзаю сеттер `innerHTML` у самого `svg` элемента или у любого его родителя (причём неважно что писать, например `document.body.innerHTML+='horses are sexy'`), то тэг `svg` и его полигон тут же оживают и мой прямоугольник отрисовывается как положено. Полагаю это происходит вследствие ререндера HTMLя.

Как я дошёл до такого, есть ли этому феномену объяснение и могу ли я дальше жить без этого костыля?

Записал ГИФку для наглядности: https://ibb.co/8jbqk1X

Провёл некоторые эксперименты:

- Если перенести `svg` тэг в отдельный `.svg` файл и добавлять через `img`, то прямоугольник отображается сразу.
- Если перенести весь мой `HTML` код в отдельный `.html` файл и запустить без сервера, то прямоугольник отображается сразу.
- Если запустить этот `.html` файл через сервер, то тоже всё впорядке.
- Однако если попробовать создать `svg` файл через `JS`, то поведение повторяется как описано в посте. Кажется, я вплотную подошёл к разгадке...
- Да, так оно и есть, `document.createElement('svg').toString()` выдаёт `[object HTMLUnknownElement]`, а это означает, что `svg` тэг нельзя создавать при помощи `createElement` функции. Ищу решение...

Comment: добавьте атрибут `viewbox=0,0,300,300` тегу `<svg >`

Comment: @StrangerintheQ он ни на что не реагирует, пока я не заюзаю `innerHTML`. Ваш код не исключение.

Comment: @StrangerintheQ я отвечу, там есть нюансы или давай вместе отвечать

Comment: @Alexandr_TT я на мобилке

Comment: @MaximLensky fill черный по дефолту

Comment: @MaximLensky в фаерфоксе отрисовывается точно также, как на кодепене так и у меня.

Comment: скорее всего имеет место опечатка, нужен оригинальный нерабочий пример

Comment: @StrangerintheQ действительно так ...

Comment: @StrangerintheQ я же написал, у меня отрисовывается как положено, но только после того как я заюзаю `innerHTML`

Comment: @Diskyp мое предположение - до изменения innerHTML у вас синтаксическая ошибка(вроде незакрытого тега), а потом браузер ее чинит в момент вставки нового контента.

Comment: @StrangerintheQ сейчас попробовал намеренно допустить ошибку (написал 'ponts' вместо 'points') и заюзал `innerHTML`, опечатка не исправилась. К тому же я копипастил с указанного в посте кодепена, который работает, если не верите мне, то могу сделать скрин из инспектора.

Comment: и тем не менее нерабочий пример в студию, иначе это лечение по фотографии

Comment: @Diskyp и такую ошибку никто не исправит, я говорил про нарушение xml а не про замену атрибута

Comment: @StrangerintheQ оххх... Он нерабочий ровно до того момента, как я не заюзаю рандомным образом `innerHTML`, а затем он становится рабочим и он написан в кодепене и в самом посте. Что ещё вы от меня хотите?

Comment: в кодепен же нету innerHTML ммм но svg отображается же

Comment: @MaximLensky верно, это и добавляет парадоксальности ситуации или наводит на мысль, что у меня проблемы с настройкой сервера, но я не могу найти зацепку.

Comment: Саша написал ответ только что - сделайте так и проверьте и отпишитесь

Comment: @Diskyp у Вас не закрыт тег `body`

Comment: Записал гифку с демонстрацией проблемы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если кто столкнётся с такой же проблемой в будущем, хотя я весьма сомневаюсь, то вот в чём дело:

Мой фреймворк создавал `svg` элемент из шаблона при помощи функции `createElement` и я не подозревал, что это может являться причиной, так как ошибок не было и сам элемент на экране отображался как обычно. В итоге фреймворк генерировал примерно такой код:

```
let qwe=document.createElement('svg'),
asd=document.createElement('polygon')
asd.setAttribute('points','10 20, 300 10, 300 120, 10 80')
qwe.appendChild(asd)
document.body.appendChild(qwe)
```

Но чтобы через `JS` создавать элементы с особым `namespace`, нужно использовать функцию `createElementNS`. Решением стал следующий код:

```
let qwe=document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg"),
asd=document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "polygon")
asd.setAttribute('points','10 20, 300 10, 300 120, 10 80')
qwe.appendChild(asd)
document.body.appendChild(qwe)
```

Именно поэтому элемент начинал отображаться только после того, как я производил повторный рендинг страницы из строки при помощи `innerHTML`.

Comment: @MaximLensky думаю неудивительно, что мой собственный, написанный с нуля, какой же ещё мог такой косяк выдать?

Comment: @MaximLensky хэй, не вырывай из контекста, мы там с сервером и отдачей файлов разбирались. Про клиент речь не заходила, поэтому факт с фреймворком был упущен.

Comment: @MaximLensky ну дак никто кроме меня самого незнает синтаксиса моего фреймворка и особенностей его работы, это было бы глупо, но возможно пораньше натолкнуло бы на нужную мысль.

Comment: @Diskyp `"Если кто столкнётся с такой же проблемой в будущем, хотя я весьма сомневаюсь"`  Ошибаетесь - С этой проблемой сталкиваются все новички.

Comment: @MaximLensky сплошь и рядом такое, когда SVG создается с помощью JS и у нас можно найти и на Enso топики с этой проблемой  https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsvg%5D+createElementNS

Comment: @MaximLensky Ну так об этом и речь, что ТС не смог правильно определить причину в вопросе и неправильно сформулировал вопрос

Answer (score 3):

Ниже пример с указанием `viewBox` и `namespace` SVG.

`viewBox` нужен для масштабирования, но чтобы это заработало, необходимо указывать либо SVG в процентах, либо у родительского блока вместо фиксированных размеров задать проценты.

`namespace` - `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg`.  Для современные браузеров можно не указывать. Но есть нюансы использования SVG, когда это необходимо.

```css
svg {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px dashed red;
 
  }
  .poly {
    fill: black;
    stroke: blue;
    stroke-width:2px;
   }
```

```html
  <body>
       <div class="block2">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 300 300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >
          <polygon class="poly" points="10 20, 300 10, 300 120, 10 80"/>
        </svg>
      </div>
      </body>
```

Если у вас всё равно не работает, тогда вам нужно добавить на ваш сервер [SVG MIME Types image/svg+xml](https://svg-art.ru/?p=1649) в статье написано, как это делается

Для Node.js посмотрите [этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11649493/7394871) с `web.config`.

`<mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml"/>`

Comment: Я всё это пробовал, попробовал снова, эффекта нет. СВГ начинает реагировать только после использования `innerHTML`. Сейчас попробую записать гифку для лучшего понимания ситуации, наверное.

Comment: @Diskyp посмотрите ссылку, которую я указал. Скорее всего в этом причина. не указано на сервере - SVG MIME Types image/svg+xml

Comment: У меня написанный с нуля сервер на ноде, здесь имеется ввиду отправлять `content-type` заголовок как `image/svg+xml` вместо `text/html`, правильно?

Comment: @Diskyp вы попробуйте сделать, как в статье написано, а потом другие варианты пробуйте

Comment: У меня нет .php файлов и htaccess файла, которые указаны в статье. У меня весь сервер на одном js файле.

Comment: @Diskyp значит пробуйте, как хотели сделать. Но этот тип  `SVG MIME Types image/svg+xml` должен быть обязательно загружен, чтобы заработало SVG

Comment: Насколько мне известно, данный тип передаётся вместе с картинками, а не веб-страницами, к тому же сам SVG у меня отрабатывает и я вижу результат, но только после того как я использовал `innerHTML`. В любом случае сейчас попробую.

Comment: Как и ожидалось, браузер незнает что делать с ХТМЛем при таком контент тайпе и выдаёт рендеринг эррор.

Comment: @Diskyp Если сохранить файл  *.svg и отдельно запустить его в браузере он ведь работает? Значит всё дело в настройках вашего сервера. Попробуйте вызвать этот сохраненный файл из HTML  с помощью тега <img src="">

Comment: Сейчас попробую перенести код в отдельный файл.

Comment: Да, если через `img` вставлять, то сразу отображается, без костылей. Скорее всего что-то с сервером, но у меня нет зацепки что может вызывать такие сложности.

Comment: Извини, но мне не подходит решение с сохранением в отдельный файл.

Comment: Пока не вижу способов как в этом убедиться, потому и задаю вопрос тут, чтобы помогли разобраться. Сохранение в картинку будет костылём, причём даже более страшным, чем рандомное использование `innerHTML`.

Comment: @Diskyp посмотрите в моём ответе, нашел пост на Enso для добавления Mime type для Node.js

Comment: А ну дак там речь ведётся о SVG файлах, а не о `svg` тэге. У меня на сервере уже давно сделана отдача корректных mime типов для файлов с соответствующими расширениями, поэтому SVG картинка, когда я код в неё перенёс, отображалась корректно. У меня именно с тэгом очень странная ситуация и я пытаюсь именно её решить.

Comment: И да, такого файла у меня тоже нет, если изволите настаивать. У меня вся серверная логика, в том числе и отдача файлов, написана вручную в одном файле и я за неё ручаюсь.

Comment: @Diskyp пробовали использовать нормальный сервер?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ сервер даже не нужен, я понял, что проблема из за моего фреймворка и создания элемента через JS, продолжаю эксперименты.